# How to do XML canonical comparison with PostgreSQL?

Tags: xml, postgresql, compare

I need to compare XML values with PostgreSQL 9.X. Example:

```sql
 SELECT 1 FROM t WHERE xml1=xml2; -- error for XML datatype
```

but can do only with casting to *text* datatype,

```sql
 SELECT 1 FROM t WHERE xml1::text=xml2::text; -- OK, but is a text-comparison
```

that is not the best way to do this. I need a better comparison algorithm... Looking for it, I find that, perhaps, "Canonical XML" can be compared.

How to do "Canonical XML comparison" with PostgreSQL?

---

**NOTE**: PostgreSQL team assumes false premisse about XML comparison?

Many documents about XML comparison sugest that *Canonical XML* is the reference format for that operation. Ex. [at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_XML) they say,

> According to the W3C, if two XML documents have the same canonical form, then the two documents are logically equivalent within the given application context.

But, [PostgreSQL docs/9.2](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-xml.html#AEN7027) says,

> The xml data type is unusual in that it does not provide any comparison operators. This is because there is no well-defined and universally useful comparison algorithm for XML data.

Well, for me it is a [false premise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_premise), and can be hiden a real lack of an important PostgreSQL issue.

Comment: Your statement is correct. Feel free to add a topological sort & canonalize (sp?) feature plus a compare operator, and submit it as a patch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I contributed to the XML type implementation in PostgreSQL and probably wrote most of the documentation you are citing.

There are a number of reasons why this is currently the way it is:

- The SQL standard specifies no comparison operator for type `xml`.
- At the time the implementation was started, Canonical XML wasn't widely used and understood (at least by the people involved, arguably).
- There are certain limitations where XML canonicalization doesn't work.  Although these might be rarely seen in practice, this would yield the situation where some values of a data type can't be compared, which would lead to problems with indexing for example.  (The NaN value of floating-point types is assigned an ordering position for similar reasons.)
- It's still debatable whether comparison by canonicalization is appropriate for all uses and what users always want.

An implementation of an XML canonicalization function for optional use would certainly be welcome.  I would actually like to see a separate `xmlcanonical` type, but that would be quite a bit more work.

Comment: First of all: humanity saves millions of dollars with PostgreSQL; all of you, who collaborate to this big software, be blessed! Thanks a lot for your work with the software and documentation!  And, of course, thanks for the answer. Personally, for me is like  a "official position" about the question, so a definitive answer.

Comment: PostgreSQL with XML standards is so important... How the public can vote for show that is a priority? (ex. vote to prioritize `xmlcanonical type` implementation)

Comment: Investments, of time or money, need return. Investment into a module of public software is good if the module is a public priority... See this site here (stackoverflow), we have a very good  mechanism (!) to register votes, and to subside to weighted vote-context and voted-itens. See the PostgreSQL site: only a [primitive mailing lists](http://www.postgresql.org/community/lists/)...  ;-).  Well, I can help PostgreSQL community to install and manage something like [askbot](https://github.com/ASKBOT/askbot-devel).

Comment: OK, I am not a C or C++ programmer... PostreSQL Wiki is great for open colaboration. So, I can help talking/writing and "voting" (lobby?)... I am creating my "[Hello worl page](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/User:Ppkrauss)" at the PostgreSQL Wiki... Created. What can I do now, that will help to advance `xmlcanonical type`?  Adding a tip into the [XML_Todo wiki-page](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/XML_Todo#XML)?  Some documentation?

Comment: @PeterKrauss you could always create a bounty for the `xmlcanonical` type, or even https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_XML to parallel the `jsonb` type.