# How to compare XML for equality in PostgreSQL

Tags: xml, postgresql, comparison

I have created a table in PostgreSQL which contains an XML column. I am using the `text` data type for that column. Now I have one sample XML which is stored in one field as following in the table:

```xml
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Now I have created one procedure which compares 2 XML data. If XML data is found it returns true else false

The problem is if the XML data is stored in one line in table like

```xml
<note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>
```

Then it gives the desired output, but if it is stored in different lines, then it returns `null`.

My procedure looks like the following

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION comparexml(p_name_in VARCHAR(255), p_xml_data_in text, out p_id integer)AS $BODY$

DECLARE
V_ID INTEGER;

BEGIN

SELECT id INTO v_id
FROM employee 
WHERE XML_DATA = p_xml_data_in and
NAME=p_name_in;


IF(v_id IS NULL) THEN
V_ID := 0;
ELSE
V_ID := 1;
END IF;

p_id=v_id;

END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: show your queries no idea what you want.

Comment: @EvanCarroll - My function looks like the following


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION comparexml(p_name_in VARCHAR(255), p_xml_data_in text, out p_id integer)AS $BODY$

DECLARE
V_ID INTEGER;

BEGIN

SELECT id INTO v_id
FROM employee 
WHERE XML_DATA = p_xml_data_in and
NAME=p_name_in;


IF(v_id IS NULL) THEN
V_ID := 0;
ELSE
V_ID := 1;
END IF;

p_id=v_id;

END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

Comment: update the question and format that thing...

Comment: @EvanCarroll - done!

Comment: your function does not return anything. And you said you compare two xml, but all you have in code is check if it is null

Comment: SELECT id INTO v_id
FROM employee 
WHERE XML_DATA = p_xml_data_in and
NAME=p_name_in;

This query checks whether record is present or not. If the record is not present, then it will store null in v_id and it will return 0 to me else if the record is present, it will store id of that record will and return 1 to me. My requirement is just to check whether the record is present or not by comparing xml and name.

Comment: Why on earth do you want to store XML in a column in the first place?

Comment: Can you actual provide sample data. Show the schema for the table. Show the insert statement to get the data in the table. Show the query not working. Come on, you can ask a better question than this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do XML canonical comparison with PostgreSQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393026/how-to-do-xml-canonical-comparison-with-postgresql)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you care if one XML document equals another. If you're searching using this qualification, you're probably  (but not certainly) doing it wrong. This is not what XML is for. You can search on the existence of something in XML..

```
CREATE TABLE foo AS SELECT xmlparse(DOCUMENT xml) AS xmlcol
FROM ( VALUES
  ($$<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
$$),
  ($$ <note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note> $$)
) AS t(xml);
```

But you should not care whether `foo.xmlcol = p_xml_data_in`. Try an

- an id on the table.
- an id in the xml.

That said, if this is important to you, you could perhaps [bribe the guy who write this answer and committed the xml code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15466698/124486). PostgreSQL does not currently have a `canonicalxml` type, but it could be implemented, and it's on the [TODO](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/XML_Todo#XML) (and likely to remain there for a long while)

> XML Canonical: Convert XML documents to canonical form to compare them. libxml2 has support for this.

Comment: I did some research and tried some practical scenarios and what i came to know is its not the problem with sameline or newline xml(as mentioned in question). Postgre can compare both type of xml. Actually it depends on how it is stored in the table.

<note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>

Comment: --continuation of above comment

Here this xml has been sent by person in one line but in the table it is stored in two lines(as per the example given in this comment, it took the new line from the ng><body> tag). The person doesn't know how it is stored in the table. So while comparing he will pass the xml in single line(in the same way as he passed at the time of inserting) which will compare the xml of table which is stored in 2 lines(new line from ng><body> tag which will but obvious give the different result).

Comment: --Continuation of above comment.
So actually that is where the difference lies.
If someone can help on this that would be great.

Comment: It's simply not true. PostgreSQL does *nothing* to an XML datatype. Perhaps the pager that **you** are using is wrapping it. If you're on linux try `PAGER="less -S" psql`

Answer (score -1):

With a little help of [plpython](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpython.html) and [lxml](http://lxml.de/) you can clear your xml a bit:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION xmlclean(xml_doc text) RETURNS text AS
$BODY$

from lxml import etree
parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)

return etree.tostring(etree.XML(xml_doc, parser=parser))

$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

Sample usage:

```
postgres=# select xmlclean('<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don''t forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>');
                                                             xmlclean                                             
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 <note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>
(1 row)
```

and:

```
postgres=# select xmlclean('<note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don''t forget me this weekend!</body></note>');
                                                     xmlclean                                                     
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 <note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>
(1 row)
```

However, it's still not perfect: what if tags order is different (I guess semantic would stay the same, i.e. they should be considered equal but obviously they wouldn't)

Comment: If you're comparing with eq you don't want to clean it. You want to canonicalize it. http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._ElementTree-class.html#write_c14n